# JoltTransformJSON processor in NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input:

```
{ "table": [{
            "_id": {
              "personId": 1234,
              "customer": 345,
              "locale": "en"
          }} ] }
```

Need output in this format, what should be my Jolt Spec

```
{
"table": [{
          "personId": 1234,
          "customer": 345,
          "locale": "en"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below example:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "table": {
        // table items
        "*": {
          // internal object in item under "_id" key
          "*": "table[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @user3533870, are you sure? I have tested it using [online jolt](http://www.jolt-demo.appspot.com/). I used your `JSON` `payload` and my `transformation` and it prints the same result as you wanted.

Comment: sorry it is working now, i have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "_id": {
            "personId": "table[&2].personId",
            "customer": "table[&2].customer",
            "locale": "table[&2].locale"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```